# ¿Porque recientemente varios sitios piden permiso para usar cookies?

Tags: html

Recientemente he notado que son varios los sitios que piden permiso para poder usar cookies y antes no lo hacían, ¿alguien sabe porque? ¿Es algo que tenga que aplicar en mis sitios web?

Tengo una tienda en linea con wordpress y woocommerce y soy de México.

Comment: Es por culpa de la llamada "Cookie law". De todas maneras esta pregunta es offtopic en Stack Overflow

Comment: Como comenta Carlos se debe a una norma de la Unión Europea para preservar la privacidad electrónica, mirate [esto](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm#section_2) si te interesa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes pedir permiso e informar el uso de cookies deacuerdo a la legislación de cada país. "Las leyes de la Unión Europea (UE) exigen que informes a tus visitantes de la UE de que usas cookies en tus sitios Web. En muchos casos, la ley también exige que obtengas el consentimiento de los lectores."

Cordial Saludo.

Comment: Por cuestiones legales, siempre, de otra forma te las cuelan y ni te das cuenta.